# function as JSX - React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want this function to be displayed in JSX code

```
function getValue() {
const QuestionChild = ['zara','whats up1','have u ever been in uk1']
const randomItem = QuestionChild[Math.floor(Math.random() * QuestionChild.length)];
console.log(randomItem)
return randomItem
}
```

Console log shows this result but can't be displayed in code

Here is JSX:

```
                <TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.btnBack}><Text style={styles.smallwowo}>Back</Text></View> 
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text>{getValue}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> {getValue} }>
             <View style={styles.btn}><Text style={styles.wowo}>Next</Text></View>
             </TouchableOpacity>
```

When Next button will be clicked it should return randomly chosen string from Question array

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** to use hooks and to separate `getValue()` from state-related concerns:

Leave your `getValue` function the same as you originally had.

Somewhere at the top of your component:

```
const [randomValue, setRandomValue] = useState(getValue());
```

Then somewhere below that create a new `onPress` handler:

```
const onGetNewValue = () => setRandomValue(getValue());
```

Then in your `onPress` statement:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onGetNewValue}>
```

And where you actually display the value would be

```
<Text>{randomValue}</Text>
```

**Old answer:**

First, to actually display the value, you need to actually call the function, so use

`<Text>{getValue()}</Text>`

Next, to have the button press change the value, you need to store the value in a state, which will trigger a re-render. There are different ways of doing this, but I would suggest in your constructor, create

`this.state = { randomValue: getValue() }`

Then in `getValue` do

```
...
const randomItem = QuestionChild[Math.floor(Math.random() * QuestionChild.length)];
this.setState({ randomValue: randomItem });
```

then instead, use

```
<Text>{this.state.randomValue}</Text>
```

Now, every time the button is clicked, a new value will be stored to state, and your component will be re-rendered with the new state value.

Comment: Very nice thanks but can you tell it with useState because i am passing navigation so it would be more comfortable

Answer (score 0):

you should store some state -- whether via `useState` or via a stateful component -- and have the `getValue` function change that state.

Then you would do `<TouchableOpacity onPress={getValue}>`, not `onPress={()=> {getValue} }`

Comment: I edited but there is error which says I am calling hooks incorectly

Comment: const [result,setResult] = useState('')
const QuestionChild = ['zara','whats up1','have u ever been in uk1']
const randomItem = QuestionChild[Math.floor(Math.random() * QuestionChild.length)];




function getValue() {
const QuestionChild = ['zara','whats up1','have u ever been in uk1']
const randomItem = QuestionChild[Math.floor(Math.random() * QuestionChild.length)];
console.log(randomItem)
setResult(randomItem)

}`

Comment: @NERD here's how I did it in the browser, the general idea should be the same in react native: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-rto65?file=/src/index.js:0-912